# .htaccess redirect url with controller name for MVC application

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i am trying to build a mvc like application and i cant figure out the right .htaccess i need.

I want something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ $1.php?action=$2&n=$3 [L]
```

so  i can access the file that contains the proper controller and two get variables from the url. The code above doesnt work, i have been around this for 2 days now and i cant find anything like what i need anywhere.What happens there is that the 3 variables are required at the url in order to work, and thats not what i want. Sugestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\./]*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

then

```
$route = explode('/', $_GET['route']);
$id = array_pop();
$controller = array_shift($route);
$method = implode('_', $route);

$controller = new $controller;
$controller->$method();
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for, i know it s an old post but i forgot to set this to be the valid answer. I used something like that but that is the idea. Thank you @Ali.

Answer (score 3):

Most frameworks use a [Front-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) instead of `mod_rewrite`. This controller splits apart the URL and *routes* accordingly.

While not the only solution, this is more flexible. Consider when you have the URL `plugin/controller/view/id` or `controller/view/param1/param2`.

If you want to adopt the Front-Controller architecture, I'd recommend using `FallbackResource` to keep your **htaccess** file trim.

```
FallbackResource /front-controller.php
```

From there it should be fairly straightforward to split apart the url with functions like [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am not using any framework, it is just a mvc based application, just raw php from scratch.

Comment: +1 (when my daily vote limit timeout expires) for `FallbackResource`. Wish I would've know about this sooner. When the front controller receives the request, do you know what the state of the `$_SERVER` array is? Will `REQUEST_URI` contain the requested resource that fell back to the FVC like with `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: It became available in Apache 2.2.17+ I believe. And yes, it should maintain the `REQUEST_URI`.

Comment: @Bruno Pires Lavigne Quintanilh, I understand. My answer still applies.

Comment: @BrunoPiresLavigneQuintanilh , just because you are not using a framework does not mean. that the method is not appropriate. Using something like *FrontController* lets you have much better control over routing system. Also it lets you create DB-based routing, which is very good for thing link multilingual URL and SEO-friendly product listing. Another thing that you seem to miss is - **Apache is not the only webserver**.

Comment: Ok, i will give it a try. I am using apache by the way.